# Unsupported Model for windows 10

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop

Hi All my laptop is restarted and having some updates from very long so i manually switched off and now if i am trying to reopen it first show blue window that critical process died and then it state Automatic repair and then below screen appear i tried multiple times but no luck

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for your hardware was removed in a recent update so when you applied it, you now get this message.

To confirm, go to the Microsoft link below and look at the supported hardware:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/windows-processor-requirements

Comment: How can I fix this issue I don't want to loose my data as I am working on critical work

Comment: If your data is as critical as you say it is, then you should have full backups. Reinstall the OS from scratch.

Comment: Thank you is it possible of taking back up of my hard disk c drive while reinstall os from scratch ?

Comment: The best you can do is, if you had a hard drive docking station then you could pull the files off it that you need before wiping the drive and reinstalling the OS.